# Requesting review of rejected tag wiki edit

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, tag-wiki

I made a tag wiki edit for the tag [slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slideshow), which had no excerpt or wiki.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30868795

The edit was rejected for the following reasons:

1. The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
2. This is blatantly incorrect

How anyone can come to the conclusion that an empty wiki's quality is not improved by writing a wiki of some quality greater than zero is beyond my comprehension.

And being able to interpret my first statement of a slideshow being a generic term referring to a few different presentation programs as "blatantly incorrect" is delusional at best and targeted harassment at worst.

I want a second opinion and for my suggested edit to be given a fair trial.

Comment: A slideshow isn't a program. A slideshow is something which can be _shown_ by a program. PowerPoint isn't a slideshow, it allows the creation and presentation of slideshows.

Comment: I wanted to upvote your post but I didn't because of the "targeted harassment" claim. Since there is no evidence to support that, I would encourage you to remove that sentence from the post.

Comment: “targeted harassment at worst.” - Edit proposals being decline is not harassment. QED.  Any second opinion I might have had, was swayed the other way, by that false claim of harassment. You call wolf, when there was no wolf, so this huntsmen is going back to bed

Comment: @Nick Technically, a slideshow _can_ be called a program but I agree with you that using the word "program" there isn't accurate. The suggested edit did not claim, however, that PowerPoint is a slideshow.

Comment: Tangentially: Is there any value on the tag itself at all?

Comment: The rejection was correct, there's no harassment, and none of the reviewers were delusional.

Comment: Speaking of review... what a mess this tag is, it is dire need of a disambiguation request in the first place and not a wiki.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how to say this more gently, but the quality really *isn't* greater than zero because it's incorrect. An incorrect tag Wiki is worse than none at all.

Also, the fact that the description referred to so many types of things indicates that the *entire tag* is potentially problematic. Adding a tag Wiki to a tag that probably shouldn't exist in the first place is putting lipstick on a pig, which is a waste of everyone's time.

I really don't see evidence of delusional behavior, targeted harassment, or an unfair process. The suggested edit went through the same process that everyone's suggested edits go through, and the reviewers disagreed. I'm guessing that just about everyone here has had suggested edits rejected at some point (I certainly have); while no one enjoys having that happen, it's part of the process.

You are, of course, free to appeal the decision on Meta if you disagree with it; reviewers aren't perfect. That being said, I would urge you to assume good intent in doing so; it seems quite unfair on the face of it to accuse them of being delusional and deliberately harassing you just for saying that your suggested tag Wiki was wrong.